# Could I have two parameters in one attribute for android data binding?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have read the custom setter in this blog. https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-custom-setters-55a25a7aea47#.7ylt58pzz

I wonder if I could use such things like the following

in xml

```
android:imageUrl="@{param1,param2}"
```

in java class

```
@BindingAdapter(value={"imageUrl"}, requireAll=false)
public static void setImageUrl(ImageView imageView, String url,
        Drawable placeHolder) {
    if (url == null) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
    } else {
        MyImageLoader.loadInto(imageView, url, placeholder);
    }
}
```

**One attribute with two parameters inside the view**. Since I have seen the lambdas expression in the android databinding (actually it is not really compiled with JDK 8) https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#listener_binding , the task variable can be add in the handler event.

```
android:onClick="@{(theView) -> presenter.onSaveClick(theView, task)}"
```

Is it possible to have two (or more)  parameters in the custom binding method ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable number of arguments to databinding adapter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257367/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-databinding-adapter)

Answer (score 6):

It's also working.

```
@BindingAdapter({"imageUrl", "error"})
public static void imageLoader(ImageView imageView, String url, Drawable error) {
    Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(url).into(imageView);
}

<ImageView
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:clickable="false"
    app:imageUrl='@{imgUrl ?? "http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/7a8aed7bjw1f2zwrqkmwoj20f00lg0v7.jpg"}'
    app:error="@{@drawable/ic_image_load_error}"
    />
```